# On this particular elliptic curve, how can I construct a function with a prescribed set of poles and zeros?

Tags: elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Consider the elliptic curve given by $E: Y^2 = X^3-X$ over the field $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_5$. I have computed the $\mathbb{F}_5$-rational points (in projective space, where $(0:1:0)$ is taken as the point at infinity):
\begin{matrix}
\textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} \\
(0:1:0) & & & \\
(0:0:1) & (0:1:0) & & \\
(1:0:1) & (0:1:0) & & \\
(2:1:1) & (0:0:1) & (2:4:1) & (0:1:0) \\ 
(2:4:1) & (0:0:1) & (2:1:1) & (0:1:0) \\
(3:2:1) & (0:0:1) & (3:3:1) & (0:1:0) \\
(3:3:1) & (0:0:1) & (3:2:1) & (0:1:0) \\ 
(4:0:1) & (0:1:0) & & \\
\end{matrix}
The numbers in the top row indicate the number of times I have added the element in the first column to itself. So each row below the top row is $a,2a, \dots ,na$, where $n$ is the order of $a$. I guess all the information in the table is not strictly related to the question.

**Question:** How can I construct a function $g \in k(E)$ that has a simple zero at each of the points in the table of order $4$, and a simple pole at each of the other points in the table, and no other zeros and poles on $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_5)$?

Comment: I don't understand your table, Are you saying that $E(\Bbb F_5)$ is cyclic of order $8$?

Comment: Isn't $(4:0:1)$ of order $2$?

Comment: So when you double it you get the point at infinity?

Comment: See the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you aright, then try
$$\frac{(x-2)(x-3)}y=\frac{x^2+1}{y}.$$
The numerator vanishes for $x\in\{2,3\}$, that is at the points of order $4$
and the denominator vanishes at the points of order $2$. On degree grounds
you must have a pole at the point at infinity too.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a general construction for functions vanishing on prescribed zeros and poles on elliptic curves over (arbitrary?) fields?

Comment: Certainly over an algebraically closed field, one can represent any principal divisor as a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of divisors $(P_1)+(P_2)+(-P_1+P_2)-3(O)$ which are divisors of functions $ax+by+c$.